# Backbone: No data added to model on fetch()

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, backbone.js

I have problems when i try to fetch data to my Backbone model from the server. You get a response in `JSON` from from the server which I think looks to be right formatted. Can you see anything wrong with it? It looks like:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Fawad Hassan","email":"fawad@test.com"},{"id":"2","name":"Bill 
Gates","email":"bill@test.com"},{"id":"3","name":"Steve 
Jobs","email":"steve@test.com"},{"id":"4","name":"Naveed 
Ahmad","email":"naveed@test.com"},{"id":"5","name":"Mr Zee","email":"zee@test.com"}]
```

My code for the Backbone project looks like this, and I can't really find the problem there either.

```
window.AppModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function() {
        return 'http://dev.local/ci/index.php/site/userpost';
    }
});

window.AppContr = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: AppModel,
    initialize: function() {
        this.model = new AppModel;
    }
});

window.App = new AppContr({name: "Markus"});

window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#content"),
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log(App.model.toJSON());
    }
});

App.model.fetch();
window.View = new AppView;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are doing a `fetch` on a Model, but returning Collection in response. That is main problem.

Second problem is that you are calling `render` on AppView totally random, i.e. it does not have anything to do with `model` or `collection`. Maybe there would be nothing in `model` when you render view. You should bind rendering to `collection` or `model` with `bind`. Than whenever you call `fetch` your view will re-render, which is one of main benefits of Backbone :)

Here comes the code :)

```
window.Person = Backbone.Model.extend({});

window.Addressbook = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'http://dev.local/ci/index.php/site/userpost',// declare url in collection
    model: Person
}

window.Addresses = new AddressBook();

window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#content'),
    initialize: function() {
        Addresses.bind('reset', this.render); // bind rendering to Addresses.fetch()
    },
    render: function(){
        console.log(Addresses.toJSON());
    }
});

window.appview = new AppView();
Addresses.fetch();
```

Comment: So how does this change if you are using the view to render a single model (without a collection)?